# How can I interrupt this alarm without exceptions?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, alarm

I have an alarm that will play a sound at a specific time. I'm looking for a way to stop it from running, how can I do it?

This is my alarm's code :

```
        waiter = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (Thread.currentThread() == waiter) {
                Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (getAlarmHours() == d.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
                    if (getAlarmMinutes() == d.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
                        UserInterface
                        .setAlarmText("no alarms");
                        playSound.play();
                        isSoundPlaying = true;

                        break;

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    });
```

I'd like to re-use the alarm again, any suggestions on where I might be going wrong would be appreciated. If I use `wait()`, how can I notify without getting exceptions?

Comment: This code will consume 100% of cpu until it triggers. I suggest you sleep for atleast a second between checks.

Comment: you'r right , thanks..whenever i run the program my pc start lagging..thanks again! ill make some changes now

Comment: You should have a look a the condition in your while loop. After starting the thread it may never end. BTW: I've never seen this construct and I've no idea how it behaves at runtime.

Comment: I _almost_ deleted this question. Please take notes of my edits. By asking questions on Stack Overflow, you are soliciting help from peers that have a lot more experience than you. Try to capitalize words that should be, while avoiding 'text speak' like `wanna'. Treat us like professionals and you'll get answers _from professionals_.

Answer (score 0):

```
waiter.interrupt();
```

also, inside your while loop, maybe put a Thread.sleep(100);

Answer (score 0):

I have written some fictional code that should help . [code](http://pastebin.com/Wpurm1tx)
you can modify the solution to look like your program if that is what you wish

Comment: Your `boolean` flag will need to be `volatile`. That being said, why not just use `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` as your loop condition, and when you want to terminate the thread, issue an `interrupt()`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving your code from a while loop to some form of a Timer.

Some common recommendations will be the [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class build into the JVM or [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which is a 3rd party library from Terracotta.

For an example of your alarm problem using standard JVM options

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
//Start the alarm now, change the date object to your specific time
timer.schedule(new AlarmTimerTask(), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

And your AlarmTimerTask Class would be

```
public class AlarmTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run(){
     //Do something
  }
}
```

if at any point you want to remove the timer (shut it off or app is closing) call `timer.cancel()` to remove the task.

Quartz will provide you with added functionality and a good library to learn

Edit: I should point out that if you assign the AlarmTimerTask class to its own variable instead of initializing it in the schedule() method, you can call cancel() on the individual task as well, and not just the Timer

Comment: sounds intresting i think im gonna use it,sounds way easier..thanks man